# Controller redirect to wrong location in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, controllers, redirect, paths

I have a controller where I created a redirect to `checkout/#payment` like this

```
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/#payment');

    return $resultRedirect;
```

When I access the controller, it redirect me at the right path, but when the page it's almost done, it change the link into `checkout/noroute/` and i recive 404.

Does anyone know why this happen?

Comment: This works, but it does not maintain the details of the checkout. It does not maintain the state. Do you know how to maintain state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$resultRedirect->setPath('checkout', ['_fragment'=>'payment']);
```